# Is it possible to give keyframes an offset of value - not time - in Graph Editor?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I am not talking about shifting keyframes in time, I am talking about selecting a bunch of keyframes and move them in value.

Suppose I have 3 rotation Z keyframes like this:

```
t = 0   ... rotation Z = 100
t = 1   ... rotation Z = 120
t = 2   ... rotation Z = 130
```

Then I apply an offset of 32 to all three and they become

```
t = 0   ... rotation Z = 132
t = 1   ... rotation Z = 152
t = 2   ... rotation Z = 162
```

So they change in value not time.

Is that possible on Blender?

I have hundreds of keyframes to change like that. I would be fine to have some automated/easy way to do that. Maya can do that easy but because I am new to Blender I am not sure if it can be done on it.

Moving the keyframes with the mouse will not do the trick. I need the operation to be precise.

Thanks

Comment: Select the keyframes you want to translate.  Then press gy32  g is translate, y is move along y axis and 32 is the amount.  This is consistent across blender.

Comment: Brilliant! Please convert this comment to an answer so I can accept.